# Boost async main thread callback

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost, boost-thread

First time using threads in C++. I've been looking at using boost which is very confusing for me. Basically all I'm trying to do is:

1. Create a worker thread that does some work asynchronously. Continue main thread while work is being done.
2. When the worker thread is done, fire a callback function with some results that executes in the main thread context.

So something similar to thread handling in C#.

There doesn't seem to be any support for 2. Using an io_service together with an async function, and thereafter using run() on the io_service seems to block the main thread. So not very asynchronous.

I've tried using boost::future as per the example here: [Using boost::future with "then" continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597948/using-boostfuture-with-then-continuations)

Here the "then" continuation is done in a separate thread, not the main thread, so not what I'm after. Is there any way to alter this? Using boost::launch::deferred and wait() makes the call synchronous, so that doesn't help either. Same with just using get() on the boost::future construct.

It seems the only option is to create a mutex-locked shared event queue, and just poll it continuously for new data in the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual to preempt the main thread in whatever it was doing to start working on the callback. Even in "thread handling in C#" (which is quite a broad subject) the main thread will typically process callbacks when it is processing the thread's [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

So typically, the main thread only executes callbacks when it is ready to do so. One way of implementing that is by calling run() on an io_service.

Your main thread can only process one message queue at a time. If your application happens to be a Windows GUI application, then your main thread is already processing a message queue (the windows message queue) and should not perform a blocking function call like run() on an IO service (which is handling another message queue). In such a case, you can decide to write code that wraps your callback in a windows event message and process that.

If you happen to be using Qt, then the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001032/how-to-integrate-boost-asio-main-loop-in-gui-framework-like-qt4-or-gtk) shows you how you could combine an asio io_service with your message loop (I haven't tried that one).

If your process is not a GUI application, then, since you already seem to be somewhat familiar with asio, you could still use an io_service. In that case however, **all** functions that the main thread performs (after initialization) should be run as events on that message queue. For example: "Continue main thread" in your question could then be implemented as another callback on the io_service.